# Lightning Network: node image

Tags: lightning-network, ln-node-identity

When browsing explorer.acinq.co, I noticed some nodes display an icon image in front of their name. 
How can I configure such an icon for my own node with LND?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign an alias to your node. The als is what is being depicted in node explorers. It is a regular utf8 string. Nowerdays there are a lot of icons as characters in utf8 encoded strings. For example ⚡.
So in lnd and in clightning (apparently both have the same Syntax) you could add the following line to your config file:

`alias=⚡my node name with icons⚡`

After restarting your node and waiting until the gossip protocol has propagated your new alias you will be able to see it on node explorers.

Comment: thanks! Is this config setting available in LND as well to your knowledge?

Comment: Yeah lnd also supports setting your node's alias just don't know the exact Syntax